# Firebug lite. Embed without hitting external or local network. Embed as inline script.

Tags: firebug, mozilla, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools, firebug-lite

I am **trying** to **feed** the **contents** of the **script** with a **body** rather than add a **script** tag with a **url**.

I have my reasons. Don't ask why. Please.

However, firebug lite  seems to by default read the url of it's script, i guess amongst them to read the default states such as

```
  '#startOpened'
```

Is there **ANY** way you can embed firebug lite **without actually loading** a src script? But by executing the contents? Is there **any global flags** that can be set prior?

Comment: Firebug Lite is not maintained for several years. The alternatives for it are the developer tools built into the browsers. If you insist to use Firebug Lite, did you try to copy its contents and paste them into a <script> tag inside the page?

Comment: @SebastianZartner Yes, I did. I am using the contents. That's what the question is about. Does the developer tools allow you hook them into a random/external browser? You imply that I have to use a specific browser with developer tools. However, the entire case for Firebug lite is that you can add it on demand. I am not a browser choose environment unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried to embed Firebug Lite completely into a website, though I think to remember that Firebug Lite stores its configuration in a cookie. And I [found some related code](https://github.com/firebug/firebug-lite/blob/master/build/firebug-lite-debug.js#L124-L138) that seems to confirm that reading from a cookie called `FirebugLite`. So, you may set those cookie values manually to configure it.

The other option you have is to change the default values of the options by [adjusting them within the code](https://github.com/firebug/firebug-lite/blob/master/build/firebug-lite-debug.js#L253-L273).

Having said that, if you're using a browser, you should rather use the built-in developer tools, as they provide a much richer feature set and are continuously updated.

Also, the Firefox DevTools team is [working on splitting their tools from Firefox](https://github.com/devtools-html), so that it's possible to use them in any browser. Though, at the moment, the only fully functional tool is the [Debugger](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html), and it requires to be run as a separate website (which doesn't seem to be possible for you if I understand you correctly).

Comment: I will look into it soon hopefully.